# Cloud run with database migrations

Tags: google-cloud-run

I would like to run db migrations in cloud run entrypoint (e.g. php artisan migrate) to avoid having to use an external tool to run these before promoting a revision.

In kubernetes this functionality can be achieved by having an init container on a deployment run the migrations and setting max surge to 1, ensuring only one pod attempts the migration before rolling out to other containers.

Is the rollout strategy of CloudRun defined anywhere? It would be nice if CloudRun waited for one container in a revision to be healthy before cutting over wholesale, which would meet this purpose (although it's not too bad of a problem with postgres transactional DDL if multiple containers attempt a migration). I think this is the behaviour I observe but not sure.

Is there a better/low-maintenance way to run the migrations than have it run in every entrypoint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In kubernetes this functionality can be achieved by having an init container on a deployment run the migrations and setting max surge to 1, ensuring only one pod attempts the migration before rolling out to other containers.

This is not a good practice in general, even in Kubernetes.

Ideally your DB migration code should be [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence#Computer_science_meaning). Especially in serverless world you will find the lack of these primitives surprising unless you shift the mindset and thinking about these concepts.

Cloud Run's rollout strategy is through configuring manual traffic splitting –which routes traffic between revisions based on percentages you define.

You can develop a new revision of a Cloud Run Service, receiving 0% traffic.

Upon deployment of a Revision, Cloud Run will still run at least one container, to see if the application becomes ready (i.e. the process starts listening on PORT). Though, you probably should not rely on *only 1 instance* coming up during this process, as that's not a guaranteed behavior.

Using this trick, you can perform a DB migration (note the "Limits" section of documentation for startup timeouts) **before** listening on the PORT number. But you need to write some logic (or use an external locking/synchronization mechanism) to make sure that code path is not executed over and over  again in the future (or simultaneously while the migration is  happening).

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies things. The db migrations are idempotent (in laravel) and are also fault-tolerant (only in postgres), so simultaneous attempts will not result in data corruption and a separate locking solution is not required. It's just preferable to avoid the errors of other container migrations failing if doing say 10 simultaneous attempts. I'm aware the method described above does not guarantee only one concurrent attempt, but is the cleanest without resorting to e.g pre-install hooks in helm. I found however that running `artisan migrate` in the entrypoint every time was too slow

Comment: I'm also using cloud run managed, so can't do traffic splitting. My initial testing suggests running `php artisan migrate` in the entrypoint everytime was too slow and affected the pod startup time, but that may be resolveable with more inspection.

Comment: My bad, traffic splitting is coming to fully-managed Cloud Run soon, stay tuned.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't readiness probe on Cloud Run. When you deploy a new revision:

- The container is downloaded
- The container is started

  - If the container start failed -> Error message
  - Else, switch the traffic configuration to the new revision

By this last step, the new traffic is routed to the new revision, the previously received request and already routed to the previous revision continue to be processed on the previous instance.

That is the simple version. In case of sustainable traffic, with several instances in parallel, it's more complex.

Hope these inputs help you!

Comment: Thanks!  The latter case is what I'm interested in. Say 10 containers running at revision 1, revision 2 deployed, does it spin up 11th container and wait until healthy, or does it spin up 11 and 12 at same time (equivalent to 25% rollout strategy for k8s deployment).

Another question, I don't see the actual healthcheck listed anywhere, is it a HttpGet against $PORT?

Comment: When the container starts, the check is done on: Is the process is running? Is the expected port is Open? No special health check, maybe a day. About the rolling update when there is several instances, there is no clear and definitive solution. There always evolutions on Google side. As far as I know, the traffic is routed when the most of instance have been updated.